# How do I create a file in FUSE in C?

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems, fuse

For an assignment we have to build a FUSE file system using C. I am trying to create an empty file in the mountpoint directory that I have mounted when I start fuse but it's not working.

I tried placing the following inside my own implementation of the fuse init function:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("data.0", "w");
fclose(fp);
```

After I had done that, what happened when I tried to navigate to the mountpoint was that I got an error: `Transport endpoint is not connected`.

When I tried to run FUSE in debug mode using `-d` flag, the terminal and FUSE froze and then I wasn't even able to navigate to the directory containing the mount point.

Then instead I placed the following inside my implementation of read:

```
mknod("data.0", 33206, 20); // a mode of 33206 means that it's a regular file with permissions 666
```

And then when I looked at the result of having called `mknod()` I got a return value of `-1` (error) and an `errno` of `1` (operation not permitted).

If I call my read function again (by opening a file), now I still get a return value of `-1` (error) but an 1 `errno` of `13` (Permission denied). Note that there is only one file in the directory and it's only there because my `readdir` function fills the buffer with that file's name. There isn't a physical file in the directory.

I'm probably approaching this all wrong. 
How do I create an empty file?

Is FUSE only an in memory thing?

OK maybe it might be better to ask this:
If I wanted to create a FUSE file system and all that it did was create a physical empty file in the mountpoint and let you access that file, how would I do that?

Comment: FUSE is definitely not restricted to being in-memory only.  Since you're getting a not permitted error, I would verify that the location (path) is writeable for you outside of your user-space filesystem.

Comment: Hm ok then at least that means that what I'm trying to do can be done. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when FUSE is started, it starts of at  the root directory, "/" not the mountpoint that you specified. So by running something such as inside `init`:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("data.0", "w+");
fclose(fp);
```

FUSE was crashing because the command is being run as the logged user who has no permissions to write in the root directory ("/").

This was resolved by attempting to create a folder in "/", granting everyone full permissions, and then writing to that folder:

```
sudo -s
cd /
mkdir data
chmod 777 data
```

And then in fuse `init`:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("/data/data.0", "w+");
fclose(fp);
```